# Can't get to submit form. Binding not applied

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am fairly new to node.js and jade. I am trying to do a form submit and somehow not able to get the bindings right. The code looks like this:

index.jade:

```
.opinion-form
      form(name="submitResponse",method="post",action="/submitResponse")
      .row
        .col-lg-12.col-md-12
          input(id="feedbackYes", type="radio", name="feedback",value=1)
          label(for="feedbackYes") Oh yeah!
      .row
        .col-lg-12.col-md-12
          input(id="feedbackNo", type="radio", name="feedback",value=0)
          label(for="feedbackNo") Nope, it's not for me.
      input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", value="SUBMIT")
    .row
      .col-lg-12.col-md-12
```

app.js

```
app.post('/submitResponse', routes.submitResponse(dbClient));
```

index.js

```
exports.submitResponse = function(dbClient) {
return function(req, res) {
    var feedback = req.body.feedback;
    // save the value to database using the dbClient
    console.log(feedback);
    res.render('thankyou')
  }
}
```

What is going wrong in this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was that the button was not inside the form, that is why no binding was applied on it. JADE and its indentation.. :( . Fixed now..

Answer (score 0):

first of not call directly `routes.submitResponse()` but let express call itself.

`app.js`

```
app.post('submitResponse',routes.submitResponse);
```

Then for the route, the way you write its like a middleware thats not the case if don't want a middleware also try to end the request with either `res.json` or `res.send` or `res.render`. It should be like this

`index.js`

```
exports.submitResponse=function(req,res,next){
 res.json(200,req.body); // end response
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to demo the actual code, but it still doesn't work. Please help me fix it..